# how can I get the selected term of a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy

Taxonomy name is "intro". I'm inside a shortcode so I dont need to echo.I need a variable for the selected taxonomy term to put in the return.
What I do has no effect

```
$terms2 = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'intro',array('fields' => 'names'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
$term_name = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'intro')[0]->name;
```